# Displaying png/jpg image with ruby tkextlib/tkimg - image not found

Tags: ruby, image, tk-toolkit

I have trouble displaying png/jpg image with ruby and tkextlib/tkimg

```
require 'tkextlib/tkimg'
root = TkRoot.new
root.title = "Window"

image = TkPhotoImage.new(:file => "/path/to/image.png")

label = TkLabel.new(root)
label.image = image
label.place('height' => image.height,
        'width' => image.width,
        'x' => 10, 'y' => 10)
Tk.mainloop
```

the error:

```
/Users/dragon/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.4/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tk/package.rb:86:in `rescue in require': TkPackage dlopen(/System/Library/Tcl/8.5/Img1.4/libtkimgwindow1.4.dylib, 10): image not found (RuntimeError)
from /Users/dragon/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.4/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tk/package.rb:83:in `require'
from /Users/dragon/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.4/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tkextlib/tkimg.rb:16:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/dragon/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.4/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
from /Users/dragon/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.4/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
from main.rb:1:in `<main>'
```

The code works with any *.gif type image but with jpg/png type of image it gives me the image not found error, but I'am 100% sure that the image exist at specified path.

also, tkextlib/tkimg should work with that types of images.

please help. Thank you.

ruby 2.2.4, os x: 10.11.6

also there should be no problem with priviledges as the image displays in similar code in python.

I tried to google a bit, but the code shown up should work.

also, is there any other way to display jpg image in ruby?

Comment: It looks like the tkimg package is not installed.  The error is not from loading the PNG, it is from trying to load the tkimg package.

Comment: but it seems that it is installed, as it run when i try gif image. hmm how can I install it?

Comment: gif support is built in to Tk.  Tk 8.6 includes built-in support for png.  The tkimg package has support for many different image types.  You appear to have a little bit older version of Tk and tkimg is not installed.  I don't know ruby or gems so I don't know how to install it.

Answer (score 1):

Your code works fine on my computer, for either jpg or png, with absolute or relative path. Do you have any "weird" character in your path name, like a whitespace?
To be sure, you could try :

```
image_path = "/path/to/image.png"
puts File.exists?(image_path)
image = TkPhotoImage.new(:file => image_path)
```

ruby 2.0.0p481 on Mac Os X 10.9.5

Comment: yes, the path and image exists. I probably try update the ruby or what.

Comment: Does File.exists?(image_path) return true?